# Theoretical Immunity of dimensions of the Monte Carlo Method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, monte-carlo

I am having a question to a paper I am reading. In his introduction the author writes the following:

[image]

I am not sure why this should be the case. The central limit theorem does not give some form of convergence rate and therefore I am not seeing that the MC method is immune to the dimension because of that.

Could somebody elaborate why this is the case? Would still be very interested in it.

---

For interested readers - it is the following publication: 
[Deep Primal-Dual Algorithm for BSDEs: Applications of Machine Learning to CVA and IM](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3071506)

Comment: Sorry for pushing this but this seems like being a good and quite interesting question to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) *does* give a (probabilistic) rate of convergence. Using the notation of the linked Wikipedia article you have
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)\ \xrightarrow{d}\ N\left(0,\sigma^2\right).
$$
This means, that the rate of convergence is $O(1/\sqrt{n})$. If you don't see this from the formula directly, think of the limit being a good approximation for large $n$, then you obtain:
$$
S_n - \mu\ \stackrel{\rm approx.}{\sim}\ N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right),
$$
which means that the standard deviation of the empirical mean $S_n$ from the true mean $\mu$ is approximately $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a (linear or not) PDE equation in $\mathbb{R}^d$ in the form
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \nu(t, x) = \mathcal{L} \nu (t, x)  $$
and you want to solve it numerically, or at least compute some macroscopic quantities which depends on the solution, such as 
$$ a_t = \int_{\mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^d}{ f(x) \nu(t, x) }.$$

Standard methods such as Finite Volume method or Finite element method would require first to discretize the region of $\mathbb{R}^d$ on which you want to compute the solution. This does not scale well with the dimension $d$.

Now assume you can find a probabilistic interpretation of the PDE in the sense that you find a stochastic process $(X_t)$ such that the law of $X_t$ is a solution of your PDE (sometimes called the Fokker-Planck PDE associated to the process):
$$\forall t \geq 0,\quad \mathcal{L}(X_t)(dx) = \nu(t, x) dx.$$

Then, it holds that
$$ a_t = \mathbb{E} f(X_t), $$
and then you can compute $a_t$ using Monte-Carlos method, by first simulating i.i.d. trajectories $(X^i_t)$ and using the approximation
$$ a_t \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k= 1}^N {f(X^i_t)}.$$

The advantage of this method is that it is usually independent of the dimension of the problem (as long as the probabilistic interpretation of the PDE behaves nicely in large $d$,
 -  that is $\text{Var} f(X_t)$ behaves reasonably well with $d$) and consequently scale well with $d$. However for small $d$ the method is usually not competitive with standard numerical PDE techniques. Also you have to find a probabilistic interpretation of the PDE, which is not always possible.